I need to keep data on the device with Jetpack compose multiplatform
I am developing an application that will work for both desktop and android with Jetpack compose multiplatform. I am new to multiplatform, I was an android developer before, but I did not need to save data to the device, which database should I use in this regard? And which one should I work with for multiplatform
I found room database but usually resources show the installation of android and ios applications for kmp I need installation for desktop I am looking for resource suggestions

Room database is also available for desktop. Please refer this (Room Kotlin Multiplatform).

for android, you can use old ways in Android development.
for desktop and ios you can use this:
actual class DatabaseImpl : Database {
private val db: MyDatabase = MyDatabase(
SqlDriver.create() // Initialize SQLDelight database driver for the platform
)
actual override fun insertItem(item: MyEntity) {
    db.myQueries.insertItem(item)
}

actual override fun getItems(): List<MyEntity> {
    return db.myQueries.selectAllItems().executeAsList()
   }
}


The Room from KMP is good regardless of its alpha version. I tested it on Android and IOS works fine.
